# Pdf rendering issues with pupeteer

Tags: node.js, pdf

Bonjour/ HI,

I fork a small projet including a NodeJs small script with pupeteer to generate a pdf of a web page

I have some rendering issues and no clue on what to do, if it's possible (i took this project for web page generation and python... don't do NodeJS apart this case)

- "Expérience" bloc jumps to page 2 (main bloc)
- "skills" bloc jump to page 2 (right column)
- blue skin of right column disappear on page 2 and nexts

Sources :
- code on gitlab https://gitlab.com/davidchalon/cv/-/blob/master/pdf.js
- wbe page with pdf : https://davidchalon.gitlab.io/cv/cv.html

Thx for your answers

Comment: Follow-up : i'm looking on weasyprint and pdfkit. Currently solving docker alpine install of weasyprint to test ...

Comment: You might try Gotenberg — this is Docker-powered API for converting to PDF. I wrote small JS/TS client for Gotenberg — https://github.com/yumauri/gotenberg-js-client